# Dark mode development in Android apps

Tags: android

I'm currently working on adding a dark mode feature to my Android app to enhance user experience and provide better accessibility. I've read through the official Android developer guidelines on supporting dark theme, but I'm looking for some practical advice and best practices from the community.

What I've done so far:

Enabled dark mode in my app's manifest by using uiMode="nightYes".
Used AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode() to switch between modes.
Defined color schemes for dark and light modes in res/values/colors.xml and res/values-night/colors.xml.

My questions are:

How do I ensure that my app's dark mode is compatible with different Android versions, especially older ones?
Are there any common pitfalls or issues I should be aware of when testing dark mode on various devices?

Comment: regarding older versions of android you can do API check if its older than android 7.0 to just keep the white mode. As far as I remember dark mode was introduced in android 7.